# Should I report a cryptocurrency transaction with a $0 capital gain?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax

I'm reporting my cryptocurrency trades on 2018 Form 8949.

For some of them, after rounding to the nearest cent, the gain is $0.00.

Should I still include those rows even if there's no capital gain or loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should.  You want to show that there is no taxable gain on the transaction.

Comment: OK, thank you. Luckily, that's what I did.